# Access element from v-on event handler in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus, el-plus

It is not infrequent that I need to access the element of a component, in vue. For instance here in element-plus, to make sure that the focus is removed:

```
<el-button ref="btnLanza" @mouseleave="$refs.btnLanza.$el.blur()" @click="runLanza" round>Lanzar</el-button>
```

In other frameworks, something along the lines of `on-mouseleave="this.blur()"` would be enough, but in vue `this` is not pointing to the element, so I need to define a ref and then go across the $refs, only for this small task.

Is there an alternate *$this* to access the component where the event is captured instead of the component where the template is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with an inline function and use the target blur method without defining the ref:

```
@mouseleave="($event)=>$event.target.blur()"
```

or just `@mouseleave="$event.target.blur()"`

it's inspired by [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components)